# Get Memory Usage in Android

Tags: android, cpu-usage

Is there any API by which we can get CPU or Memory usage of android?

I have tried one code as below:

```
package com.infostretch.mainactivity;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class CPULoad 
{
    long total = 0;
    long idle = 0;

    float usage = 0;

    public CPULoad()
    {
        readUsage();
    }

    public float getUsage()
    {
        readUsage();
        return usage;
    }

    private void readUsage()
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/proc/stat")), 1000);
            String load = reader.readLine();
            reader.close();

            String[] toks = load.split(" ");

            long currTotal = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3]) + Long.parseLong(toks[4]);
            long currIdle = Long.parseLong(toks[5]);

            this.usage = (currTotal - total) * 100.0f / (currTotal - total + currIdle - idle);
            this.total = currTotal;
            this.idle = currIdle;
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Maybe one you will accept an answer...

Comment: o/p what i am getting is not the correct ... all the time o/p is in the range of 0.825699 to 1.0 , only one app is running on my android phone. I download the free app from google play for the cpu usage check but both o/p is different different. Can you tell me what o/p I'm getting from tv.setText(" "+readCPUUsage());

Comment: Android studio now has a memory tab that will get you all the info on the app running.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I use this function to calculate cpu usage. Hope it can help you.

```
private float readUsage() {
    try {
        RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/stat", "r");
        String load = reader.readLine();

        String[] toks = load.split(" +");  // Split on one or more spaces

        long idle1 = Long.parseLong(toks[4]);
        long cpu1 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3]) + Long.parseLong(toks[5])
              + Long.parseLong(toks[6]) + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(360);
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        reader.seek(0);
        load = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();

        toks = load.split(" +");

        long idle2 = Long.parseLong(toks[4]);
        long cpu2 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3]) + Long.parseLong(toks[5])
            + Long.parseLong(toks[6]) + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);

        return (float)(cpu2 - cpu1) / ((cpu2 + idle2) - (cpu1 + idle1));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you only have 1 CPU?

Comment: What? This code works for any number of processors and gives the cpu usage for all processors combined.

Comment: This is quite ridicules, but I get 1.0, which I assume is 100% most of the time, although the device has no apps running...

Comment: Hey, I thought I'd add a few pieces of information that it took me a while to figure out while trying to understand this algorithm. If you want to find CPU per core, you want to skip the first line and read all subsequent lines that contain CPU, however the token index's need to be decremented by an additional 1. (first line has two spaces after CPU for delimiter). All of the CPU's are not always in this file since Android may shut off a core to save power. This blog explains why you need multiple measurements to get accurate results.  http://www.pplusdomain.net/cgi-bin/blosxom.cgi/2009/04/02

Comment: @Dave can you please care you share your version of the code?

Comment: @KhurramMajeed I didn't end up keeping my code, as per core CPU wasn't required. But it didn't take long to write it up. The first thing you need to know is the number of CPU cores. This question has a function that can do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962155/how-can-you-detect-a-dual-core-cpu-on-an-android-device-from-code , Then you use the code above but IGNORE the first line.  Then have a loop that goes through and records the CPU of each core and idle into two array lists.  Sleep your thread for a bit, then have another loop that records the CPU and idle for each core again.

Comment: Then do some math similar to above to get the CPU values per core. Since you are ignoring the first line, the token delimiters will change to this. long idle1 = Long.parseLong(toks[4]);
        long cpu1 = Long.parseLong(toks[1]) + Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3])
              + Long.parseLong(toks[5]) + Long.parseLong(toks[6]) + Long.parseLong(toks[7]);  Hope this helps!

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the info, Firstly I want to calculate total CPU usage and not invidual cores, so does it make any difference to the accuracy of the value. Secondly, I have asked this question, [in my SOF question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17723475/777593).. so if you can post answer with a code snippet it will great and I will be able to mark it as correct answer if it works.

Comment: It'd be nice if this were more easily accessible, this is a very expensive function (About 350ms by my measurement)

Comment: It takes time because there is a call to Thread.sleep(). There must be a duration to compute the CPU usages. You may put this code in a background thread.

Comment: o/p what i am getting is not the correct ... all the time o/p is in the range of 0.825699 to 1.0 , only one app is running on my android phone. I download the free app from google play for the cpu usage check but both o/p is different different. Can you tell me what o/p I'm getting from tv.setText(" "+readCPUUsage());

Comment: Why Long.parseLong(toks[1]) is missing in the total sum?

Comment: cz toks[1] dont have any value. this is debug values. `cpu  1477 206 3688 184114 4313 0 366 0 0 0` then toks have 
`toks[]
 0 = "cpu"
 1 = ""
 2 = "1477"
 3 = "206"
 4 = "3688"
 5 = "184114"
 6 = "4313"
 7 = "0"
 8 = "366"
 9 = "0"
 10 = "0"
 11 = "0"`

Comment: `Thread.sleep(360);` Are you serious? oO I *strongly* advise against using your code in a real world app.

Comment: cpu usage will be in percent ? how can i get the usage in percentage. iam getting the values like 0.073529415

Answer (score 40):

An easy way to check the CPU usage is to use the adb tool w/ top. I.e.:

`adb shell top -m 10`

Comment: don't you mean : "adb shell top -n 1" ?

Comment: Though this is correct, my question was about Android API not about any tool

Comment: isn't a question was about memory usage, guys?

Answer (score 17):

Based on the previous answers and personnal experience, here is the code I use to monitor CPU use. The code of this class is written in pure Java.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

/**
 * Utilities available only on Linux Operating System.
 * 
 * <p>
 * A typical use is to assign a thread to CPU monitoring:
 * </p>
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &#064;Override
 * public void run() {
 *  while (CpuUtil.monitorCpu) {
 * 
 *      LinuxUtils linuxUtils = new LinuxUtils();
 * 
 *      int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
 *      String cpuStat1 = linuxUtils.readSystemStat();
 *      String pidStat1 = linuxUtils.readProcessStat(pid);
 * 
 *      try {
 *          Thread.sleep(CPU_WINDOW);
 *      } catch (Exception e) {
 *      }
 * 
 *      String cpuStat2 = linuxUtils.readSystemStat();
 *      String pidStat2 = linuxUtils.readProcessStat(pid);
 * 
 *      float cpu = linuxUtils.getSystemCpuUsage(cpuStat1, cpuStat2);
 *      if (cpu &gt;= 0.0f) {
 *          _printLine(mOutput, &quot;total&quot;, Float.toString(cpu));
 *      }
 * 
 *      String[] toks = cpuStat1.split(&quot; &quot;);
 *      long cpu1 = linuxUtils.getSystemUptime(toks);
 * 
 *      toks = cpuStat2.split(&quot; &quot;);
 *      long cpu2 = linuxUtils.getSystemUptime(toks);
 * 
 *      cpu = linuxUtils.getProcessCpuUsage(pidStat1, pidStat2, cpu2 - cpu1);
 *      if (cpu &gt;= 0.0f) {
 *          _printLine(mOutput, &quot;&quot; + pid, Float.toString(cpu));
 *      }
 * 
 *      try {
 *          synchronized (this) {
 *              wait(CPU_REFRESH_RATE);
 *          }
 *      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
 *          e.printStackTrace();
 *          return;
 *      }
 *  }
 * 
 *  Log.i(&quot;THREAD CPU&quot;, &quot;Finishing&quot;);
 * }
 * </pre>
 */
public final class LinuxUtils {

    // Warning: there appears to be an issue with the column index with android linux:
    // it was observed that on most present devices there are actually
    // two spaces between the 'cpu' of the first column and the value of 
    // the next column with data. The thing is the index of the idle 
    // column should have been 4 and the first column with data should have index 1. 
    // The indexes defined below are coping with the double space situation.
    // If your file contains only one space then use index 1 and 4 instead of 2 and 5.
    // A better way to deal with this problem may be to use a split method 
    // not preserving blanks or compute an offset and add it to the indexes 1 and 4.

    private static final int FIRST_SYS_CPU_COLUMN_INDEX = 2;

    private static final int IDLE_SYS_CPU_COLUMN_INDEX = 5;

    /** Return the first line of /proc/stat or null if failed. */
    public String readSystemStat() {

        RandomAccessFile reader = null;
        String load = null;

        try {
            reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/stat", "r");
            load = reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Streams.close(reader);
        }

        return load;
    }

    /**
     * Compute and return the total CPU usage, in percent.
     * 
     * @param start
     *            first content of /proc/stat. Not null.
     * @param end
     *            second content of /proc/stat. Not null.
     * @return 12.7 for a CPU usage of 12.7% or -1 if the value is not
     *         available.
     * @see {@link #readSystemStat()}
     */
    public float getSystemCpuUsage(String start, String end) {
        String[] stat = start.split("\\s");
        long idle1 = getSystemIdleTime(stat);
        long up1 = getSystemUptime(stat);

        stat = end.split("\\s");
        long idle2 = getSystemIdleTime(stat);
        long up2 = getSystemUptime(stat);

        // don't know how it is possible but we should care about zero and
        // negative values.
        float cpu = -1f;
        if (idle1 >= 0 && up1 >= 0 && idle2 >= 0 && up2 >= 0) {
            if ((up2 + idle2) > (up1 + idle1) && up2 >= up1) {
                cpu = (up2 - up1) / (float) ((up2 + idle2) - (up1 + idle1));
                cpu *= 100.0f;
            }
        }

        return cpu;
    }

    /**
     * Return the sum of uptimes read from /proc/stat.
     * 
     * @param stat
     *            see {@link #readSystemStat()}
     */
    public long getSystemUptime(String[] stat) {
        /*
         * (from man/5/proc) /proc/stat kernel/system statistics. Varies with
         * architecture. Common entries include: cpu 3357 0 4313 1362393
         * 
         * The amount of time, measured in units of USER_HZ (1/100ths of a
         * second on most architectures, use sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK) to obtain the
         * right value), that the system spent in user mode, user mode with low
         * priority (nice), system mode, and the idle task, respectively. The
         * last value should be USER_HZ times the second entry in the uptime
         * pseudo-file.
         * 
         * In Linux 2.6 this line includes three additional columns: iowait -
         * time waiting for I/O to complete (since 2.5.41); irq - time servicing
         * interrupts (since 2.6.0-test4); softirq - time servicing softirqs
         * (since 2.6.0-test4).
         * 
         * Since Linux 2.6.11, there is an eighth column, steal - stolen time,
         * which is the time spent in other operating systems when running in a
         * virtualized environment
         * 
         * Since Linux 2.6.24, there is a ninth column, guest, which is the time
         * spent running a virtual CPU for guest operating systems under the
         * control of the Linux kernel.
         */

        // with the following algorithm, we should cope with all versions and
        // probably new ones.
        long l = 0L;

        for (int i = FIRST_SYS_CPU_COLUMN_INDEX; i < stat.length; i++) {
            if (i != IDLE_SYS_CPU_COLUMN_INDEX ) { // bypass any idle mode. There is currently only one.
                try {
                    l += Long.parseLong(stat[i]);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    return -1L;
                }
            }
        }

        return l;
    }

    /**
     * Return the sum of idle times read from /proc/stat.
     * 
     * @param stat
     *            see {@link #readSystemStat()}
     */
    public long getSystemIdleTime(String[] stat) {
        try {
            return Long.parseLong(stat[IDLE_SYS_CPU_COLUMN_INDEX]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return -1L;
    }

    /** Return the first line of /proc/pid/stat or null if failed. */
    public String readProcessStat(int pid) {

        RandomAccessFile reader = null;
        String line = null;

        try {
            reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/" + pid + "/stat", "r");
            line = reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Streams.close(reader);
        }

        return line;
    }

    /**
     * Compute and return the CPU usage for a process, in percent.
     * 
     * <p>
     * The parameters {@code totalCpuTime} is to be the one for the same period
     * of time delimited by {@code statStart} and {@code statEnd}.
     * </p>
     * 
     * @param start
     *            first content of /proc/pid/stat. Not null.
     * @param end
     *            second content of /proc/pid/stat. Not null.
     * @return the CPU use in percent or -1f if the stats are inverted or on
     *         error
     * @param uptime
     *            sum of user and kernel times for the entire system for the
     *            same period of time.
     * @return 12.7 for a cpu usage of 12.7% or -1 if the value is not available
     *         or an error occurred.
     * @see {@link #readProcessStat(int)}
     */
    public float getProcessCpuUsage(String start, String end, long uptime) {

        String[] stat = start.split("\\s");
        long up1 = getProcessUptime(stat);

        stat = end.split("\\s");
        long up2 = getProcessUptime(stat);

        float ret = -1f;
        if (up1 >= 0 && up2 >= up1 && uptime > 0.) {
            ret = 100.f * (up2 - up1) / (float) uptime;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * Decode the fields of the file {@code /proc/pid/stat} and return (utime +
     * stime)
     * 
     * @param stat
     *            obtained with {@link #readProcessStat(int)}
     */
    public long getProcessUptime(String[] stat) {
        return Long.parseLong(stat[14]) + Long.parseLong(stat[15]);
    }

    /**
     * Decode the fields of the file {@code /proc/pid/stat} and return (cutime +
     * cstime)
     * 
     * @param stat
     *            obtained with {@link #readProcessStat(int)}
     */
    public long getProcessIdleTime(String[] stat) {
        return Long.parseLong(stat[16]) + Long.parseLong(stat[17]);
    }

    /**
     * Return the total CPU usage, in percent.
     * <p>
     * The call is blocking for the time specified by elapse.
     * </p>
     * 
     * @param elapse
     *            the time in milliseconds between reads.
     * @return 12.7 for a CPU usage of 12.7% or -1 if the value is not
     *         available.
     */
    public float syncGetSystemCpuUsage(long elapse) {

        String stat1 = readSystemStat();
        if (stat1 == null) {
            return -1.f;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(elapse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        String stat2 = readSystemStat();
        if (stat2 == null) {
            return -1.f;
        }

        return getSystemCpuUsage(stat1, stat2);
    }

    /**
     * Return the CPU usage of a process, in percent.
     * <p>
     * The call is blocking for the time specified by elapse.
     * </p>
     * 
     * @param pid
     * @param elapse
     *            the time in milliseconds between reads.
     * @return 6.32 for a CPU usage of 6.32% or -1 if the value is not
     *         available.
     */
    public float syncGetProcessCpuUsage(int pid, long elapse) {

        String pidStat1 = readProcessStat(pid);
        String totalStat1 = readSystemStat();
        if (pidStat1 == null || totalStat1 == null) {
            return -1.f;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(elapse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1.f;
        }

        String pidStat2 = readProcessStat(pid);
        String totalStat2 = readSystemStat();
        if (pidStat2 == null || totalStat2 == null) {
            return -1.f;
        }

        String[] toks = totalStat1.split("\\s");
        long cpu1 = getSystemUptime(toks);

        toks = totalStat2.split("\\s");
        long cpu2 = getSystemUptime(toks);

        return getProcessCpuUsage(pidStat1, pidStat2, cpu2 - cpu1);
    }

}
```

There are several ways of exploiting this class. You can call either `syncGetSystemCpuUsage` or `syncGetProcessCpuUsage` but each is blocking the calling thread. Since a common issue is to monitor the total CPU usage and the CPU use of the current process at the same time, I have designed a class computing both of them. That class contains a dedicated thread. The output management is implementation specific and you need to code your own.

The class can be customized by a few means. The constant `CPU_WINDOW` defines the depth of a read, i.e. the number of milliseconds between readings and computing of the corresponding CPU load. `CPU_REFRESH_RATE` is the time between each CPU load measurement. Do not set `CPU_REFRESH_RATE` to 0 because it will suspend the thread after the first read.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Application;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.util.Log;

import my.app.LinuxUtils;
import my.app.Streams;
import my.app.TestReport;
import my.app.Utils;

public final class CpuUtil {

    private static final int CPU_WINDOW = 1000;

    private static final int CPU_REFRESH_RATE = 100; // Warning: anything but > 0

    private static HandlerThread handlerThread;

    private static TestReport output;

    static {
        output = new TestReport();
        output.setDateFormat(Utils.getDateFormat(Utils.DATE_FORMAT_ENGLISH));
    }

    private static boolean monitorCpu;

    /**
     * Construct the class singleton. This method should be called in
     * {@link Application#onCreate()}
     * 
     * @param dir
     *            the parent directory
     * @param append
     *            mode
     */
    public static void setOutput(File dir, boolean append) {
        try {
            File file = new File(dir, "cpu.txt");
            output.setOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, append));
            if (!append) {
                output.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                output.newLine(1);

                // print header
                _printLine(output, "Process", "CPU%");

                output.flush();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /** Start CPU monitoring */
    public static boolean startCpuMonitoring() {
        CpuUtil.monitorCpu = true;

        handlerThread = new HandlerThread("CPU monitoring"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        handlerThread.start();

        Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (CpuUtil.monitorCpu) {

                    LinuxUtils linuxUtils = new LinuxUtils();

                    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
                    String cpuStat1 = linuxUtils.readSystemStat();
                    String pidStat1 = linuxUtils.readProcessStat(pid);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(CPU_WINDOW);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                    String cpuStat2 = linuxUtils.readSystemStat();
                    String pidStat2 = linuxUtils.readProcessStat(pid);

                    float cpu = linuxUtils
                            .getSystemCpuUsage(cpuStat1, cpuStat2);
                    if (cpu >= 0.0f) {
                        _printLine(output, "total", Float.toString(cpu));
                    }

                    String[] toks = cpuStat1.split(" ");
                    long cpu1 = linuxUtils.getSystemUptime(toks);

                    toks = cpuStat2.split(" ");
                    long cpu2 = linuxUtils.getSystemUptime(toks);

                    cpu = linuxUtils.getProcessCpuUsage(pidStat1, pidStat2,
                            cpu2 - cpu1);
                    if (cpu >= 0.0f) {
                        _printLine(output, "" + pid, Float.toString(cpu));
                    }

                    try {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            wait(CPU_REFRESH_RATE);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return;
                    }
                }

                Log.i("THREAD CPU", "Finishing");
            }

        });

        return CpuUtil.monitorCpu;
    }

    /** Stop CPU monitoring */
    public static void stopCpuMonitoring() {
        if (handlerThread != null) {
            monitorCpu = false;
            handlerThread.quit();
            handlerThread = null;
        }
    }

    /** Dispose of the object and release the resources allocated for it */
    public void dispose() {

        monitorCpu = false;

        if (output != null) {
            OutputStream os = output.getOutputStream();
            if (os != null) {
                Streams.close(os);
                output.setOutputStream(null);
            }

            output = null;
        }
    }

    private static void _printLine(TestReport output, String process, String cpu) {
        output.stampln(process + ";" + cpu);
    }

}
```

Comment: This seems to be an interesting code. However, I want to find out average CPU and average memory consumption for each experimental runtime. Can you please give some advice

Answer (score 11):

Since the OP asked about CPU usage AND memory usage (accepted answer only shows technique to get cpu usage), I'd like to recommend the ActivityManager class and specifically the accepted answer from this question: [How to get current memory usage in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170691/how-to-get-current-memory-usage-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

Check the `Debug` class. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html
i.e. `Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()`

It has methods to get the used native heap, which is i.e. used by external bitmaps in your app.
For the heap that the app is using internally, you can see that in the DDMS tool that comes with the Android SDK and is also available via Eclipse.

The native heap + the heap as indicated in the DDMS make up the total heap that your app is allocating.

For CPU usage I'm not sure if there's anything available via API/SDK.

Comment: Also see http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Debug.html#getMemoryInfo(android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo)

Comment: Hey Mathias..Thanks for your input but I found that the code works very fine. I was out side and so couldn't respond you.

Bye the way, Right now I am working on Memory usage point. I will post it code in a day or two.

Comment: Hi Mathias.. I want to find the current memory usage in mobile through my application code, and hence DDMS can't help in this scenario. SO what I have done is I have used /proc/meminfo command and parsed the response. but it shows very less free memory. So I am just confused about response.

please check my query here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170691/how-to-get-current-memory-usage-in-android

Comment: @MathiasLin Your approach only works with DDMS.  What about getting this information inside the app at runtime?

Answer (score -2):

enter the android terminal and then you can type the following commands :dumpsys cpuinfo

```
shell@android:/ $ dumpsys cpuinfo                                              
Load: 0.8 / 0.75 / 1.15
CPU usage from 69286ms to 9283ms ago with 99% awake:
  47% 1118/com.wxg.sodproject: 12% user + 35% kernel
  1.6% 1225/android.process.media: 1% user + 0.6% kernel
  1.3% 263/mpdecision: 0.1% user + 1.2% kernel
  0.1% 32747/kworker/u:1: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.1% 883/com.android.systemui: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
  0.1% 521/system_server: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 14 minor
  0.1% 1826/com.quicinc.trepn: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
  0.1% 2462/kworker/0:2: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
  0.1% 32649/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0% 118/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 179/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 46/kinteractiveup: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 141/jbd2/mmcblk0p26: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 239/sdcard: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 1171/com.xiaomi.channel:pushservice: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
  0% 1207/com.xiaomi.channel: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
  0% 32705/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
12% TOTAL: 3.2% user + 9.4% kernel + 0% iowait
```

Comment: The asker was looking for an API (Application Programming Interface) to obtain this info.

Comment: Can only be called by System Apps, so not suitable from calling within Android app as per question.