# Android - get allocated memory

Tags: android, memory-management

is there any way, how to determine actual allocated memory in Android application (in code)?

Thanks

Waypoint

Comment: Waypoint,see this ans may be helpful [Read android device total ammount of ram with /proc/meminfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869761/read-android-device-total-ammount-of-ram-with-proc-meminfo/9870018#9870018)

Comment: I am getting only total ammount of RAM, I need actual use by my application

Comment: run this command `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/top -n 50");` this will give u all processes info and then parse it

Comment: Waypoint, see this post :[How to discover memory usage of my application in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you talking about Android Application Memory then,

[`ActivityManager.getMemoryInfo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryInfo%28android.app.ActivityManager.MemoryInfo%29) is our highest-level API for looking at overall memory usage.

Going lower-level, you can use the [Debug API](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Debug.html#getMemoryInfo%28android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo%29) to get raw kernel-level information about memory usage.

Note starting with 2.0 there is also an API, [`ActivityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getProcessMemoryInfo%28int%5B%5D%29), to get this information about another process.

Also you can parse `/proc/meminfo` command. and get the response for memory information.

**EDIT:**

```
ActivityManager activityManager =  (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new MemoryInfo();
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
Log.i("memory free", "" + memoryInfo.availMem);
```

For more information look at these two SO questions:

1. [How to discover memory usage of my application in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android)
2. [How to get current memory usage in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170691/how-to-get-current-memory-usage-in-android)

Comment: Thanks but what mehotd of ActivityManager.getMemoryInfo() exactly? Noone seems to be fir for me

Comment: Thanks for your edit, I cannot parse proc/meminfo so I tried to use ActivityManager.getMemoryInfo but it shows only availMem. Nevertheless I load fields or not, availMem is not changing

Comment: In this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118234/how-to-get-memory-usage-and-cpu-usage-in-android use /proc/meminfo file for get memory info.

Comment: /proc/meminfo is giving me only maximum RAM size, i need actual allocated size