# total and free memory on android?

Tags: android, memory

I am working on an app, in which I need to display the total and available memory. I am using the following snippet; however, it works only on API 16 or above. I need something which works on all Android versions.

my question is Different from the "possible duplicates" as my question is to get memory usage **on all api levels**.

```
private void getAvailableRam() {
    MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
    long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
    ttvv.setText(availableMegs + " MB");
}

private void getTotalRamSize() {
    MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
    long totalMemory = mi.totalMem / 1048576L;
    ttvv2.setText(totalMemory + " MB");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get total device ram?I need it for an optimization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551547/is-there-a-way-to-get-total-device-rami-need-it-for-an-optimization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For getting available memory,**

You can use the same mi.availMem since min API level is 1

**For getting total memory less than API level 16**

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView ttvv2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      ttvv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ttvv2);
      ttvv2.setText(getTotalRAM());
 }

private  String getTotalRAM() {
      RandomAccessFile reader = null;
      String load = null;
      long total = 0;
      try {
           reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/meminfo", "r");
           load = reader.readLine().replaceAll("\\D+","");;
           total = Integer.parseInt(load)/1024;
      }catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      return total+" MB";
}
}
```

Hope this helps. Regards.

Source:

1) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.MemoryInfo.html

2) [Android How do you get total memory RAM in the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998713/android-how-do-you-get-total-memory-ram-in-the-device)

Comment: pass the method to textview like this **ttvv2.setText(getTotalRAM());**

Comment: You can either assign TotalRAM() to a string variable and use it in setText() or directly call the method  in setText(). I also updated the code to fetch total RAM in MB. Hope this helps. Regards.

Comment: I updated the code for full implementation. Hope this helps. Regards.

Comment: use your old getAvailableRam() method  Regards.

Comment: i want to implement this simple antivirus in my app, can you test it and find out why it force closes? ill ask a new question! https://github.com/azzzey5/androidFileScanner

Answer (score 1):

File "/proc/meminfo" is real-time memory info.
you can read it in your code

```
adb shell cat /proc/meminfo

MemTotal:        1900556 kB
MemFree:          343468 kB
Buffers:           97708 kB
Cached:           659364 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           784552 kB
Inactive:         358336 kB
Active(anon):     394596 kB
Inactive(anon):      364 kB
Active(file):     389956 kB
Inactive(file):   357972 kB
Unevictable:        1396 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
HighTotal:       1158144 kB
HighFree:          52088 kB
LowTotal:         742412 kB
LowFree:          291380 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        394552 kB
Mapped:           176752 kB
Shmem:               452 kB
Slab:              48296 kB
SReclaimable:      21808 kB
SUnreclaim:        26488 kB
KernelStack:        9632 kB
PageTables:        19276 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      950276 kB
Committed_AS:   47222076 kB
VmallocTotal:     245760 kB
VmallocUsed:       79036 kB
VmallocChunk:      75648 kB
```

Comment: im really new to programming.thanks for answering but how do i call this? and also how do i render it in my textview?