# How to get Total RAM memory of the Device?

Tags: android, performance, ram

When i run my app on LG G4 or Note 3 which has 3GB of RAM, it shows that the device has 2GB of ram. Can someone explain where is the problem?

```
    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo mi = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
    long freeMemory = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
    long totalMemory = mi.totalMem / 1048576L;
    long usedMemory = totalMemory - freeMemory;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Util.MyPREFERENCES, 0);
    String status = sharedPreferences.getString(Util.KEY_STATUS, null);
    if (status.equals("clean")) {
        tvFree.setText(freeMemory + " MB");
        tvTotal.setText(totalMemory + " MB");
        tvUsed.setText(usedMemory + " MB");
        stateImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenstate);
        rippleBackground.stopRippleAnimation();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it doesn't allow you to count the RAM required by the OS.

Comment: well, it should allow, let me check android documentation again.

Comment: That detail matters.  Is this a 64 bit JVM?  You can't get more than 1.6GB from a 32 bit JVM: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html

Comment: From Android Documentation - "The total memory accessible by the kernel. This is basically the RAM size of the device, not including below-kernel fixed allocations like DMA buffers, RAM for the baseband CPU, etc."

Comment: 32 bit JVM?  That matters.  No need for "basically" - it's a high tech "um" that adds nothing.

Comment: this answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8133438/3678308

Comment: @ExceptionLover that is for external memory "getExternalStorageDirectory"

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem to be a clear API for that but I used a simple hack:

Setup a lookup table with some of the power of 2s (like first 15-20) and find the nearest value to the "OS memory" retrieved from the API.

Had a similar problem to yours:
[Get android device's all RAM memory programmatically and not only what is only allocated to user processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442758/get-android-devices-all-ram-memory-programmatically-and-not-only-what-is-only-a)