# Display Storage and RAM information in Android

Tags: android, android-memory, android-storage

I am creating a mobile junk cleaner application and I want to show the device Storage and RAM information like Available Space and Used space and Available RAM and used RAM. Like this image. I am able to display the ram information in Text form only but I am stuck in making the circle like.
[sample which I want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGiwo.png)
here is my code :

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.codebytes.mobilebooster.util.ContextUtil;

import com.codebytes.mobilebooster.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT = 100;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING = 101;
    private boolean sentToSettings = false;
    private static MainActivity instance;

    TextView txtTotalram,txtAvailram,txtUsedram,tv;
    int progressStatus=0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    ProgressBar circle_progres;
    //Double t_ram,a_ram
    ProgressBar pb_colored;

    ImageView img_animation,img_leftanimation ;
    float  height,width;
    public static int i=1;
    private SharedPreferences permissionStatus;

    Button mJunkCleanButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        txtTotalram = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_totalram); 
        txtAvailram = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_availram); 
        txtUsedram = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_usedram); 
        pb_colored = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_colored);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        height = (displaymetrics.heightPixels);
        width =(displaymetrics.widthPixels);


        // double h = height*(1/100);
        // double w = width*(1/100);
        Log.i("heightwidth", "height" + height+"  width"+width);
        permissionStatus = getSharedPreferences("permissionStatus",MODE_PRIVATE);
        ContextUtil.sApplicationContext = this.getApplicationContext();

        mJunkCleanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.junk_clean);
        mJunkCleanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        //Show Information about why you need the permission
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Need Storage Permission");
                        builder.setMessage("This app needs storage permission.");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);

                            }
                        });
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
                    } else if (permissionStatus.getBoolean(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,false)) {
                        //Previously Permission Request was cancelled with 'Dont Ask Again',
                        // Redirect to Settings after showing Information about why you need the permission
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Need Storage Permission");
                        builder.setMessage("This app needs storage permission.");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                                sentToSettings = true;
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Go to Permissions to Grant Storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
                    } else {
                        //just request the permission
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
                    }

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = permissionStatus.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,true);
                    editor.apply();


                } else {
                    //You already have the permission, just go ahead.
                    proceedAfterPermission();
                }}

    }
    public String getTotalRAM() {

        RandomAccessFile reader = null;
        String load = null;
        DecimalFormat twoDecimalForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        double totRam = 0;
        String lastValue = "";
        try {
            reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/meminfo", "r");
            load = reader.readLine();

            // Get the Number value from the string
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(load);
            String value = "";
            while (m.find()) {
                value = m.group(1);
                // System.out.println("Ram : " + value);
            }
            reader.close();

            totRam = Double.parseDouble(value);
            // totRam = totRam / 1024;

            double mb = totRam / 1024.0;
            double gb = totRam / 1048576.0;
            double tb = totRam / 1073741824.0;

//            lastValue = twoDecimalForm.format(mb).concat(" MB");

            lastValue = twoDecimalForm.format(mb);



//            if (tb > 1) {
//                lastValue = twoDecimalForm.format(tb).concat(" TB");
//            } else if (gb > 1) {
//                lastValue = twoDecimalForm.format(gb).concat(" GB");
//            } else if (mb > 1) {
//                lastValue = twoDecimalForm.format(mb).concat(" MB");
//            } else {
//                lastValue = twoDecimalForm.format(totRam).concat(" KB");
//            }



        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Streams.close(reader);
        }

        return lastValue;
    }



    public String available_ram()
    {

        String lastValue = "";
        double totRam = 0;
        ActivityManager.MemoryInfo mi = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
        long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;

        //long availableMegs = mi.availMem ;


        DecimalFormat twoDecimalForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");


        totRam = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(availableMegs));

        double mb = totRam / 1024.0;
        double gb = totRam / 1048576.0;
        double tb = totRam / 1073741824.0;

        if (tb > 1) {
            lastValue = twoDecimalForm.format(tb).concat(" TB");
        } else if (gb > 1) {
            lastValue = twoDecimalForm.format(gb).concat(" GB");
        } else if (mb > 1) {
            lastValue = twoDecimalForm.format(mb).concat(" MB");
        } else {
            lastValue = twoDecimalForm.format(totRam).concat(" KB");
        }




        String available = String.valueOf(availableMegs);
        return available;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    private void proceedAfterPermission() {
        //We've got the permission, now we can proceed further
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "We got the Storage Permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, JunkCleanActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //The External Storage Write Permission is granted to you... Continue your left job...
                proceedAfterPermission();
            } else {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    //Show Information about why you need the permission
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Need Storage Permission");
                    builder.setMessage("This app needs storage permission");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();


                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);


                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Unable to get Permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
        String totalram =getTotalRAM().toString();
        //       txtTotalram.setText(totalram.concat(" MB"));

        String availram =available_ram().toString();

        txtAvailram.setText(availram.concat(" MB"));


        Double t_ram= Double.valueOf(totalram);
        Double a_ram = Double.valueOf(availram);

        Double used_ram = t_ram-a_ram;

        String usedram = String.valueOf(used_ram);

        txtUsedram.setText(usedram.toString().concat(" MB"));

        //  int tot = Integer.parseInt(t_ram);

        pb_colored.setMax((int) Math.round(t_ram));
        pb_colored.setProgress((int) Math.round(used_ram));

    }





    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Got Permission
                proceedAfterPermission();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        if (sentToSettings) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Got Permission
                proceedAfterPermission();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: And your question is what now?

Comment: Your question should be, "How to display numbers inside arch like view" or something like that, because to me that seems to be the problem you are trying to solve, you seemed to have already solved the "how to get ram info" problem. ProTip : Split your problems into smaller problems and solve them individually.

Comment: I googled "android arch progress bar" and found this : https://github.com/Shinelw/ColorArcProgressBar   Tip : If you know the exact problem you are trying to solve, you can google more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should read this question [How to get total RAM size of a device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374246/how-to-get-total-ram-size-of-a-device).
After create a function based on reference response above and getting information you could draw results on graphics like you want to do it.