# Android Coding (my app keeps crashing)

Tags: android

hi ive started an app and wanted to test it so i use an avd and when the app starts it crashes and i was hoping somebody could help

this is my java class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
    long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;

    TextView manufacturerTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mem);
    manufacturerTextView.setText((int) mi.availMem);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

LOGCAT

02-06 07:10:05.202: E/AndroidRuntime(771): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 07:10:05.202: E/AndroidRuntime(771): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x18184000
02-06 07:10:05.202: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-06 07:10:05.202: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-06 07:10:05.202: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-06 07:10:05.202: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)

Comment: is anyone going to help please its my only hope for my project

Comment: What exactly happens? Could you post the output of LogCat? You can find it in eclipse, or by using adb.

Comment: past the logcat output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert it to string to display

Comment: so is anyone going to look at the LOGCAT

Comment: ok it worked but why is it giving me a 9 digit number.is that kilobytes or somthing

Comment: it's in bytes not in Killobytes

Answer (score 3):

use

```
manufacturerTextView.setText(String.valueOf((int) mi.availMem));
```

instead

```
manufacturerTextView.setText((int) mi.availMem);
```

for showing Integer value in TextView

Comment: i cant put up logcat its to long

Comment: Only put up the part showing the crash.  If you don't know how, then learn about how Android uses logcat first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217500/how-to-print-stacktrace-for-an-exception-android

Comment: @user1934637 : you are getting error because of `manufacturerTextView.setText((int) mi.availMem);` line

Comment: @user1934637 : use `manufacturerTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mi.availMem));` instead of `manufacturerTextView.setText((int) mi.availMem);`

Comment: @user1934637 : any success ?

Comment: ok it worked but why is it giving me a 9 digit number.is that kilobytes or somthing

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K it worked but how can i turn the avalible memory into MB format

Comment: @user1934637 : i think u will need to show `availableMegs` in TextView instead of `mi.availMem`

Comment: @user1934637 : and also check [this](http://orion-viewer.googlecode.com/git-history/b4486e05aeb9bb114778d7a5be3052b9f04a00ba/orion_viewer/src/universe/constellation/orion/viewer/prefs/DevicePrefInfo.java) example for showing availMem in Mb

Comment: ok it worked thanks for all the help but i need just one last thing.How to i get the total device ram and just not the avaliable memory

Comment: @user1934637 : friend just make a search lots of previously  question available on same . if after searching u are not able to find any solution then comment me or make a new question for other issue then i will try to help u .

Comment: @user1934637 : have u see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935022/android-how-to-get-memory-usage-of-my-android-device) post ?