# Blurring Bitmap Efficiently

Tags: android, blur

I've run into some issues with trying to blur an image at runtime. I've posted a question already on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078499/blur-outofmemoryexception), but it was downvoted and I'm not sure why, as I haven't gone against the FAQ with the question, to the best of my knowledge.

I am trying to be able to blur an image, even on older devices, if thats possible, but as I have it right now, it will crash with an OutOfMemoryException. What I have learned, however, is that with the `fastblur` method I referenced, I cannot use anything other than `int[]`, since the Bitmap methods require `int[]`. So, my best guess on my own question would be to use the `NDK` and the [C method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11962240/1292230) for blurring. However, that doesn't completely solve my memory issues.

I figured that I could do a few things, such as check the available memory against how much memory it would cost me and/or listen for `onLowMemory()` in the `Activity` and break the blur process when that hits.

However, for the first idea, I know very little about calculating memory and usage. Given the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3192348/1292230), it looks as though I can calculate how much memory I can safely use, given:

```
MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
long availableBytes = mi.availMem;
```

Can I then check it against the approximate size of the int array, assuming that would be `a 32-bit signed two's complement integer` (width * height * 32L)? Also, how would I give it a reasonable buffer to not hurt the system performance, as well?

My best answer to myself would be to use the `NDK` and C for the blur, listen for `onLowMemory()` and also pre-calculate available memory to my estimated `Bitmap`/`int[]` memory usage using a constant value to check against (available/estimate > aConstantValue).

If I am way off, please teach me how I should do this. Otherwise, correcting where I have made mistakes in what I've said is also tremendously helpful. I am not looking to form an opinionated debate, or ambiguous question, since that would go against the FAQ. I want to build a correct solution to handle blurring and memory consumption, if possible.

Also, if your finger is itching to click downvote my question, I would greatly appreciate some harsh words, preferably in comment form, to make me realize why I am deserving of it.

Thank you!

Comment: You are referring a question that has been deleted, so it's now impossible to follow your steps when reading.