# Detecting low memory situations in .NET/Mono on mobile devices

Tags: c#, .net, memory, mobile, mono

My .NET application is running on Windows Phone, Android and iOS (via Mono).

I am looking for a way to detect low memory situations before OutOfMemory exception is thrown (or application just dies, which is what usually happens on mobile platforms).

My application has a way to instantly reduce memory usage by using a different code path. Unfortunately I need to know *when* to do so - I need to know that memory is low before I am shut down by the OS.

I am not looking for a silver bullet that will work 100% of the time. Anything that will reduce frequency of out-of-memory crashes is good.

For example, does the following make sense:

```
// Periodically (say once per a few seconds) execute the following:
try
{
    byte[] probe = new byte[1 * 1024 * 1024];
}
catch (OutOfMemoryException)
{
    // 1MB free block not found, choose low memory code path
}
```

This has the drawback of increasing the frequency of garbage collections. Is there a better way?

Nonsolutions:

- .NET MemoryFailPoint class, unfortunately it is not yet available in Mono and so is not an option.

Comment: I think you should do platform specific memory checks, here is one for android for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170691/how-to-get-current-memory-usage-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS will call `DidReceiveMemoryWarning()` on your UIViewController subclasses when you are running low on memory, allowing you to free up resources.

Android will call `OnLowMemory()` on your Activity subclasses.

I'm not sure what the equivalent on Windows Phone is, but I wouldn't be surprised if they have something similar.