# How much processing must a mobile app do?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, react-native

I am developing a mobile app and it performs too much work. (For me I think) Generating reports from my local database data takes up to 2 hours. I'm not sure if it's my algorithm, or it's the phone's limitation.

My question is, up to what extent of computation must be done by the mobile app? When do I know if I need a web server to do the computations for the app?

Additional Information:
My mobile app gets tickets from API and totals ticket metrics per month, and gets the average of each metrics per month.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170691/how-to-get-current-memory-usage-in-android

Comment: Thanks @IntelliJAmiya. It's not the answer I was looking for but it may help decode the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile app should be only a thin client for a web server application, if the computation is complicated. It's better to use the server as a power to compute everything difficult. Then send data to the mobile app. So, the app should just receive and parse JSON and display data on UI (graphs, diagrams and so on).