# Get memory and Data consumed by individual Application through code in android

Tags: android, memory, settings

Is there any way to get the mobile data and the memory consumed by an app through code. As like it show on the App setting page, I need to show the details within the app. Kindly suggest
[App Settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDaOq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using Profiler but you cant get it programatically

> https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler
>
> details about each of the profilers, see the following:
>
> Inspect CPU activity and traces with CPU Profiler Inspect the Java
>   heap and memory allocations with Memory Profiler Inspect network
>   traffic with Network Profiler Inspect energy usage with Energy
>   Profiler

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already read about the Profiler and I just posted the question to know anyone tried via code.

Answer (score 0):

For Data usage you can try this below code it will return the number of bytes received across mobile networks since device boot:

Toast.makeText(this, android.net.TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()+"Bytes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html

For memory consuption you can refer this duplicate question:

- [How to get current memory usage in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170691/how-to-get-current-memory-usage-in-android)