# Programmatically find Android system info

Tags: java, android

I am trying to programatically find the system info for Android devices, specifically:

- RAM
- CPU speed
- # cores, architecture, etc.

Are there any Android classes that specify this information.  I have been using the android.board library, but it doesn't seem to have everything that I want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let me tell you what I did, So others who visit this thread can come to know the steps:

1) parse /proc/meminfo command. You can find reference code here:
   [Get Memory Usage in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118234/how-to-get-memory-usage-and-cpu-usage-in-android)
2) use below code and get current RAM:

```
MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
```

Note: please note that - we need to calculate total memory only once. so call point 1 only once in your code and then after, you can call code of point 2 repetitively.

Answer (score 2):

You can get most of the information you want from the `/proc/cpuinfo` file. Here is a tutorial on how to load and parse that file: http://www.roman10.net/how-to-get-cpu-information-on-android/

Additionally the information about the RAM can be obtained from the `/proc/meminfo` file

Comment: meminfo will not give you the full installed ram. it gives you information about used ram. and hot it is used. so the answer is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code snippet to get the current device RAM size.

```
ActivityManager actManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
MemoryInfo memInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
actManager.getMemoryInfo(memInfo);
long totalMemory = memInfo.totalMem;
```

Answer (score 1):

Agarwal's answer was very helpful. Had to modify it a bit since I'm not calculating free memory in an activity, but passing in an application context to a system utilities file:

From the main activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        MySystemUtils systemUtils = new MySystemUtils(this); // initializations
        ...
     }
}
```

In the SystemUtils file:

```
   MySystemUtils (Context appContext) { // called once from within onCreate
        MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
        ActivityManager activityManager = ActivityManager)appContext.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
        long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
    }
```