# Find app's CPU usage on Android

Tags: java, android, cpu-usage

Is there an android API that provides CPU, memory usage of the running app? I would like to tune my processing in the app on the fly based on the cpu usage.

Comment: see this SO post :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118234/how-to-get-memory-usage-and-cpu-usage-in-android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5560634/844882). You can also get a listing using `adb` as follows,

```
adb shell top -m 10
```