# Dumpsys permission denial in java

Tags: android

I am trying to obtain the dumpsys statistics [like dumpsys cpuinfo, dumpsys battery]. I executing these in java and writing it to a file. But I am getting,

```
2012.06.20 07:32:19
Permission Denial: can't dump cpuinfo from from pid=862, uid=10040 without permission android.permission.DUMP
for all dumpsys commands.
```

I have added the permission `"android.permission.DUMP"` and `"android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"` in android.manifest. But, not obtaining the resulyPlease help as its critical.The code I use is as below where cmd contains dumpsys cpuinfo or dumpsys battery [anyone]

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Monitor/"+file+".txt",false)));
System.out.println("\n\n"+sdf.format(cal.getTime()));           
Log.w("cmd-fn", cmd);
process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
process.waitFor();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String buffer="";

while((buffer=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
      {
    //fileobj.write(buffer);
    System.out.println(buffer);
    //output.write(buffer);
}
    buffer="";
    BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
    while((buffer=buffered.readLine())!=null)
        {
        Log.w("exception",buffer);
        }
```

Below is my manifest entries

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DUMP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: Below is my maniest file. Please help <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.monitor"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DUMP"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

Comment: Try to add permission after uses-sdk

Comment: @Vipul I don't have any uses-sdk in my manifest. Please help where to find?

Answer (score 11):

The DUMP permission is defined as  `android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem"` so you can't get it unless your app is signed with the platform key, or installed in the system partition.

Comment: How to accomplish that? Please help

Comment: @Nick Is there anyother way like changing the android:protectionLevel to someother value like normal and make it work? Else how to make your app is signed with the platform key?

Comment: If you are not building a custom firmware (ROM), the only way is to root the phone.

Comment: @Nikolas I am new to android. Is there any programming way to do this? Please explain with code how to root phone or the steps. THanks. Please help

Comment: the only way to get your app installed as a system app is to own the ROM yourself, and install it there when the ROM is built (or via a ROM OTA).

Comment: Actually, it is possible to grant this permission using adb (device being connected to the PC), but for some reason using dumpsys still doesn't work, even though checking that this permission is granted -returns that it is.

Comment: Is it possible to use the dump permission using root? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

The android dev team decided to stop granting these permissions to third-party apps. Only system apps can now get them.

more details:https://code.google.com/p/acra/issues/detail?id=100

Comment: Please improve your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can provide DUMP permission from adb

```
adb shell pm grant <your-package-name> android.permission.DUMP
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access some memory information by checking /proc/meminfo file, there is also other intersting files under /proc/. Hopefully these files will be readable in future releases

Code example to fetch meminfo:

```
    public static String showMemInfo() {
    StringBuilder meminfo = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        ArrayList<String> commandLine = new ArrayList<String>();
        commandLine.add("cat");
        commandLine.add("/proc/meminfo");

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine.toArray(new String[commandLine.size()]));
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            meminfo.append(line);
            meminfo.append("\n");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Could not read /proc/meminfo", e);
    }

    return meminfo.toString();
}
```

PS: I know it's not verbose like dumpsys ;)

Answer (score -1):

There are two other ways you can use to get cpu information

1. use top command int adb shell, get most information

   ```
   top -n 1
   ```
2. You also can cat information in /proc/stat and /proc/pid/stat to get the cpu information

   ```
   cat /proc/stat
   ```

   If you wanna details, check [Get Memeory Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118234/get-memory-usage-in-android)