# Android -- get MEID from JNI

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm working in Android, writing some JNI code, and I'm looking for a way to query the Mobile Equipment Identifier (MEID) from the device.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_equipment_identifier

I'm trying to write C or C++ code that can run by itself on an Android device, so I don't think I can use Java (i.e., get MEID from `TelephonyManager`).

A search of StackOverflow finds: [Is there an android shell or adb command that I could use to get a device's IMEI/MEID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852106/is-there-an-android-shell-or-adb-command-that-i-could-use-to-get-a-devices-imei)

Okay great, `dumpsys iphonesubinfo` can get the info I need.  And it works!

I couldn't find the source for `dumpsys` except as part of the source for Android.  So I downloaded that... my hard disk filled up before the download finished, but I did get the source code to `dumpsys`.  It is a surprisingly short C++ file.  All it does is query Android's `IBinder` interface.

So, my questions:

0) Is there any way I can write a query against `IBinder` using just the stuff in the NDK?  The include files used by `dumpsys.cpp` are not in the NDK, and `grep` in the NDK directory didn't find `IBinder` in any include files or code samples, so my guess is "no" (but I would like to be wrong).

1) Is there any other good way to get the MEID?

I'm seriously thinking I should just use `system("dumpsys iphonesubinfo > /tmp/myprogname_dumpsys.tmp"` and then open the resulting file and parse it.  That should work, but I would hardly call it elegant... and I'm not sure if `dumpsys` is available on every Android device or not.

EDIT: The idea of using `system()` to run `dumpsys` will not work, because `dumpsys` needs `android.permission.DUMP` and Android no longer allows non-system apps to have that permission.

[Dumpsys permission denial in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113349/dumpsys-permission-denial-in-java)

Comment: `dumpsys` is a platform system file so I think its available on every android device.

Comment: Also if you want to write a query like `dumpsys` you can trough **NDK** but also keep in my mind you have all permissions which needed.

Comment: @user370305 -- How can I write a query like `dumpsys` through the NDK?

Comment: Use the same code, which `dumpsys` use. But I have doubt of `dumpsys` has all right to access all system files.

Comment: I cannot use the same code which `dumpsys` uses, because `dumpsys` uses code that is not in the NDK.  I don't want my code to have to depend on "secret" code that is part of the Android system source code but is not put into the NDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Dalvik implements all the same JNI interfaces that the JVM does, so while it's a bit fiddly, it's perfectly possible to make calls from native code through JNI to arbitrary Java classes and methods.

```c
/* assuming you already have */
JNIEnv *env;
jobject context;
/* then call (with error-checking) */
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/context/Context");
jmethodId mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, context_cls, "getSystemService",
    "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
jfieldID fid = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env, cls, "TELEPHONY_SERVICE",
    "Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring str = (*env)->GetStaticObjectField(env, cls, fid);
jobject telephony = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, context, mid, str);
cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/telephony/TelephonyManager");
mid =(*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "getDeviceId", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
str = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, telephony, mid);
jsize len = (*env)->GetStringUTFLength(env, str);
char* deviceId = calloc(len + 1, 1);
(*env)->GetStringUTFRegion(env, str, 0, len, deviceId);
(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, str);
/* to get a string in deviceId */
```

Comment: My test app that calls into my JNI code crashes on the `CallObjectMethod()` line.  I passed in the `jobject` instance that my JNI function got as an argument... is that the right thing to do?

Comment: I should have said this earlier: I like this approach and I hope I can get it to work.  Thank you for suggesting it.

Comment: @steveha I forgot that `TelephonyManager#getDeviceId()` is not a method on `Context`; you need to `getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)` first.  I've not tested this either, but it should be closer now.

Comment: I'm trying to make your idea work, and I have hit a roadblock.  If you can, please look at my follow-on question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103411/android-ndk-crash-in-callobjectmethod-calling-getsystemservice  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but why does `jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/context/Context");` return NULL all the time?(No problem with env)

Comment: Maybe a silly question, did you check your permission if it has READ_PHONE_STATE ?

Comment: @ephemient
I'm new to JNI and I wanna ask a question - Do you use defensive programming in your JNI code? I understand that you could skip error checks here for the sake of clarity, but do you normally check if FindClass or GetMethodID etc returned NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the MEID on the Java side, then pass into your JNI function as a `jstring` parameter. It'll be cleaner than calling back to Java from C.

As to how to retrieve that, see Abhilasha's answer.