# How to @Override/Hook with JNI

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I was trying to do `@Override` with JNI (so during runtime). This is a sample of how the override is completed in non-JNI:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // do my custom stuff here
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); // call regular
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks @JJF for your attention. I know how to call methods with JNI but I don't know how to "Create the onActivityResult" listener from JNI. It seems everyone is setting up this `@Override` prior to runtime. Because JNI is executed during runtime, I am trying to find a way to do an override during runtime, does this help make it more clear?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928459/how-to-call-an-a-overridden-super-class-method-in-java-through-jni

Comment: Thanks @Michael that calls the overridden, however I'm trying to override. Calling the super will be my second step.

Comment: The question I linked to also shows how to do a native override, which is why I linked to it. Declare your method `@Override protected native void onActivityResult(blah blah);` and then write the native implementation in your C or C++ code.

Comment: Ah thanks very much I will re-read and update you.