# android get imei in cc/c++ for ndk/JNI

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface, imei

I would try to get the `imei` of a device in C/C++ (using ndk) and retrieve the result with JNI.

```
const char *res = exec_get_out("service call iphonesubinfo 3");
```

Works in shell, but does not in my application

I have the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission set in the Manifest.  This is targeted for Marshmallow Android (and I have accepted permission in settings)

Is there any other solution that would work or is it not possible without a JNI environment?

Answer (score 1):

check [this](http://www.clearevo.com/blog/programming/2012/11/26/android_ndk_get_imei_natively.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11643923/365229)

```
#include <sys/system_properties.h>

    //returns the string length of the value.
    int ir = __system_property_get("ro.gsm.imei", imei_start);           

      if(ir > 0)
    {
      imei_start[15]=0;//strz end      
      printf("method1 got imei %s len %d\r\n",imei_start,strlen(imei_start));
      strcpy(g_imei,imei_start);
    }
      else
    {
      printf("method1 imei failed - trying method2\r\n");
      //old dumpsys imei getter
      char* res = exec_get_out("dumpsys iphonesubinfo");  
      const char* imei_start_match = "ID = ";
      int imei_start_match_len = strlen(imei_start_match);
      char* imei_start = strstr(res,imei_start_match);
      if(imei_start && strlen(imei_start)>=15+imei_start_match_len)
        {
          imei_start += imei_start_match_len;
          imei_start[15] = 0;
          printf("method2 IMEI [%s] len %d\r\n",imei_start,strlen(imei_start));
          strcpy(g_imei,imei_start);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @BB755 there is no known way to read IMEI and MAC address in android 10 and above