# how to get IMEI number from device using c code android

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-10.0, imei

I need to get IMEI number using c code into android. I tried using command but didn't get success.

Does anybody know how to get IMEI number using native code?

I tried this command

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1
```

and

```
service call iphonesubinfo 3
```

also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40743506/10989990) answer

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11643923/10989990) answer is working, but can not get success in Android 10

Comment: _"but can not get success in Android 10"_ Android 10 doesn't allow 3rd party apps to access the IMEI number. Doesn't matter if you're using native code or not.

Comment: is there any command to get IMEI number? anything which can return me that?

Comment: None that I know of. The correct solution is to design your app not to rely on an IMEI number.