# How to get IMEI number by C++ or C in Android?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I want to find a pure C/C++ way(not jni) to get my Android Device's IMEI numbers !
Does ndk-toolchains have such api to get IMEI numbers ?

Comment: _"Does ndk-toolchains have such api to get IMEI numbers ?"_ no and _"...pure C/C++ way(not jni)..."_ NDK modules are called via JNI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android get imei in cc/c++ for ndk/JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134288/android-get-imei-in-cc-c-for-ndk-jni)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.