# How Thirdparty Apps access All details about installed apps

Tags: android, memory

In my app , I am showing the memory usage of each app. I tried the solutions provided in SOF as,

> Getting from MemInfo shell command

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dumpsys meminfo " + info.packageName);
```

Permission denied to run this command.

> Tried with TOP command

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -n 1 -d 1");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
     in.readLine();
 do {
     try {
                    String trial[] = in.readLine().split(" ");
                    int j=0;
                    String array[]=new String[trial.length];
                    for(String a:trial)
                    {
                        if(!a.isEmpty()) {
                            array[j] = a;
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                    String package_name=array[9];
                    if(package_name!=null)
                    {
                        if(package_name.contains(":"))
                            package_name=package_name.substring(0,package_name.indexOf(":"));
                    }
                    publishProgress(package_name);
                    Debug.MemoryInfo[] procsMemInfo = manager.getProcessMemoryInfo(new int[] {Integer.parseInt(array[0])});
                    long memory=0;
                    for (Debug.MemoryInfo info:procsMemInfo)
                    {
                        memory+=info.getTotalPss();
                    }

                    processDescriptions.add(new ProcessDescription(array[0], Integer.parseInt(array[1]),
                            array[2], MemorySizeConverter.MBorKB_Converter((double) memory, 1), array[8], package_name));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.d("skipped",e.toString());
                }
            } while (in.readLine() != null );
```

It worked and I can get running processes memory info. Not for all installed apps.

As [this statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11115782/8867002),  My app should be signed with the platform key, or installed in the system partition to access it. But how third party apps available in playstore are accessing it . Can anyone help me.