# Measure cpu and other hardware devices load, bandwidth and memory usage

Tags: android, cpu, cpu-usage

I need to measure the load (mcps - million cycles per second), bandwidth (MBps) and memory consumption (KB) by each of the devices in android mobile phone (cpu, video accelerators, display etc). I know the procedure to get the cpu usage ([Get Memory Usage in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118234/how-to-get-memory-usage-and-cpu-usage-in-android)) but I want to know how can we do that for other hardware blocks on the mobile phone?

Is there any documentation available for the same?

Rgds,
Sapan