# How to determinate statement's cpu usage in android

Tags: java, android, cpu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Memory usage and CPU usage in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118234/how-to-get-memory-usage-and-cpu-usage-in-android)

I'm writing an android application that needs to know how much cpu/battery intensive are some statements.

For example if I call a function, I would like to know how much battery that function used, or at least something like that, for example how many clock cycles have been used.

Do you know everything I can use?

Thanks in advance

Leonardo

Comment: The best way is , Traceview. Follow this link: http://tools.android.com/recent/traceviewineclipse One more link with brief description : http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/10/traceview-war-story.html

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118234/how-to-get-memory-usage-and-cpu-usage-in-android)

Comment: Thanks guys but my question is refering a runtime environment (so i can't use traceview) and the cpu usage for a set of statement, the question pointed by Mojo is about "overall" cpu usage. But i really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

A direct way of arriving at CPU usage may not be available as of now. How ever you can use an indirect approach for calculating CPU usage.

> Calculate the diffrence in time stamps before and after you make a function call. This will give you the time duration in milis that a function takes.
>
> Now CPU usage should be directly proportional to time duration unless the function blocks on some IO operation or 'Object.wait()' or context switches.
>
> However the above approach will almost yeild descent results if your functions are only doing in memory calculations.

Comment: Yeah, currently i do exactly what you said, unfortunatly is not sufficient for my purpose. Thanks for your effort anyway.