# How to find the Memory used by particular process in android?

Tags: android, memory-management

I am struggling for a solution to find the memory used by particular process in android.

Using `actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()` I can able to get the consolidated list of all process's memory usage.

But i need to implement a scenario where I should pass the `processID` and get the memory usage of particular process? Is this scenario possible in Android?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the memory info using

```
MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
```

and for a particular process use

```
activityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo(new int[]{process_ids});
```

which returns an array of memory information

I would ask you to refere these three

[Get Memory Usage in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118234/how-to-get-memory-usage-and-cpu-usage-in-android)

[How to get current memory usage in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170691/how-to-get-current-memory-usage-in-android)

[How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

See these links:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2299813/1369222

http://macgyverdev.blogspot.in/2011/11/android-track-down-memory-leaks.html

Note that this isn't an exact science and instead of looking for a general "memory usage of a process" you should be looking for something more specific to your requirements. Anyway, those links will help you get started.