# How to get CPU usage by Running Apps

Tags: android, process, cpu-usage

I am working on an App, where I need to show the CPU usage as per running applications(just like a Task manager).

I have followed this post, [Get CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5560634/1626878), but it demonstrates the total CPU usage.
Here it has used the following code to read the CPU stats,

```
RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/stat", "r");
```

I want to get cpu usage of all individually running apps. So far, I've been able to fetch the list of all running applications,

```
      ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)
                      getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> listOfRunningProcess = activityManager
                    .getRunningAppProcesses();
```

Now I want to get the CPU usage for these applications.

Comment: Refer this  http://www.cleanappnetwork.com/tutorial-finding-cpu-usage-for-individual-android-apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use the linux [top](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm) command to get the memory usage for each process (PID).

You can find the complete implementation [here](http://www.cleanappnetwork.com/tutorial-finding-cpu-usage-for-individual-android-apps/).

Answer (score 1):

Use top command and Execute it by using `Runtime.execute("your top command")` This will give you a String and you have to parse it to get each app CPU usages.

look at here for more on [Top](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm) command.