# Display cpu,memory info in android application

Tags: android, memory, textview

I'm writing an android application displays some info about cpu, memory etc etc.. How can i display theese infos on the screen? With the textview or other way?

Comment: What is your actual problem? Or your problem is that you are not sure where to start?

Comment: My problem is that i can't find a way to display the CPU's info or memory's info in the app. With a toast yes but i want display them on the screen. For example just over a button or in the center of my activity..

Comment: o/p what i am getting is not the correct ... all the time o/p is in the range of 0.825699 to 1.0 , only one app is running on my android phone. I download the free app from google play for the cpu usage check but both o/p is different different. Can you tell me what o/p I'm getting from tv.setText(" "+readCPUUsage());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function  and Show it in `TextView`

```
private float readCPUUsage() {
    try {
        RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/stat", "r");
        String load = reader.readLine();

        String[] toks = load.split(" ");

        long idle1 = Long.parseLong(toks[5]);
        long cpu1 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3]) + Long.parseLong(toks[4])
              + Long.parseLong(toks[6]) + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(360);
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        reader.seek(0);
        load = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();

        toks = load.split(" ");

        long idle2 = Long.parseLong(toks[5]);
        long cpu2 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3]) + Long.parseLong(toks[4])
            + Long.parseLong(toks[6]) + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);

        return (float)(cpu2 - cpu1) / ((cpu2 + idle2) - (cpu1 + idle1));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For more see [How to get Memory usage and CPU usage in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118234/how-to-get-memory-usage-and-cpu-usage-in-android)

***Edit***

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        tv.setText(" "+readCPUUsage());
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

Comment: mmh, interesting..But in my case i have a nexus4 so i've got 4 CPUs. However how can i "connect" this function with the textview?

Comment: Ok thank you, but what have i to write in the textview? For example?Just a simple example to understand.

Comment: o/p what i am getting is not the correct ... all the time o/p is in the range of 0.825699 to 1.0 , only one app is running on my android phone. I download the free app from google play for the cpu usage check but both o/p is different different. Can you tell me what o/p I'm getting from tv.setText(" "+readCPUUsage());