# how can I detect resource usage of my Android app

Tags: resources

I'm developing an Android application and would like to know if there's a lot of resources (processor, memory) it needs while running. How can I detect the amount of resource usage?

Comment: It depends on the OS. Which one are you using?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Of course! It's Android. I'm developing on Eclipse for Android.

Comment: It is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3118234/3315914

Answer (score 0):

I use Ksysguard to watch the various processes but Top is good, runs in a terminal & has an enormously (1957 line) comprehensive man page.  This is in Linux of course.  I guess that MS has similar apps.