# TaskManager android that will show current memory usage and cpu usage

Tags: java, android, cpu-usage, heap-memory, taskmanager

I am making a Project on TaskManager android just like windows Taskmanager. How to get CPU usage and memory Usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use Linux commands like **`top`** or **`ps`** using:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...);
```

http://m2catalyst.com/tutorial-finding-cpu-usage-for-individual-android-apps

[Get Memory Usage in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118234/get-memory-usage-in-android?rq=1)