# Is it possible to monitor the CPU,Memory usage of each method in Android

Tags: android

I have my Android app with lots of methods and maybe each method runs for 1000s of lines. I need to monitor the CPU,memory usage in time duration(ms) of each method so that i can know which method is taking lot of CPU,memory and i can optimize it later. Is this possible? Any solution/advise would be of great help :)

Comment: `Debug mode` with `Breakpoints` and you can see your `memory leak` of each method/line.

Answer (score 1):

```
I finally found out how to do this - 

//Calculate function execution time
double start = System.currentTimeMillis();
double end = System.currentTimeMillis();
double t = (end - start);

//Calculate the amount of time that the current thread has spent executing code or waiting for certain types of I/O.
double start1 = Debug.threadCpuTimeNanos();
double end1 = Debug.threadCpuTimeNanos();
double t1 = (end1 - start1)/1000000;

//CPU Usage
double cpu = (t1/t) * 100;

//if t=0,cpu becomes infinity programmatically but it means cpu usage is 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set 2 DateTime variables, one at the start, one at the end.

```
Time start= new Time();
now.setToNow();

//Your method

Time end = new Time();
now.setToNow();
```

Distract the start from the start and see how long it takes.

Log the result: Log.I("METHOD_NAME", "duration");

Comment: This is for checking method execution time but i needed to know cpu,memory utilization of each method.

Comment: Sorry. My fault... Had to read. Maybe use this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118234/get-memory-usage-in-android/5560634#5560634

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Profiling with Traceview.

This can help you trace the timeline of each thread/method etc. Look at the link below.

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html#traceviewLayout

Comment: Does it also give me CPU, memory utilization of each method?

Comment: Well you would need to use couple of dev tools in studio to get the info you need such as https://developer.android.com/tools/performance/memory-monitor/index.html#WorkingWithMemoryMonitor and ddms

Comment: This link should give you some more idea about memory monitor, heap viewer and allocation tracker https://developer.android.com/tools/performance/comparison.html

Comment: I need to achieve this programmatically rather than using profiling or traceview.