# Best way to monitor Android system-metrics

Tags: android

I want to monitor some metrics of my Android Phone. On the one hand I want to monitor the current hardware states (e.g. battery capacity, CPU usage...). On the other hand I want an overview over the running processes with various information. My current approach is to read various files in the /proc/ directory using the execute method of the Runtime.

Are there more performant or easier ways to get these Kind of information?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use different classes Android give you:

- Battery: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html
- Memory: [How to get current memory usage in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170691/how-to-get-current-memory-usage-in-android)
- CPU: [Get Memory Usage in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118234/get-memory-usage-in-android)

Look for the others but it's quite simple.